# How to match the string in $(....) in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
with open('templates/data.xml', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
    line = line.rstrip() #removes trailing whitespace and '\n' chars

    if "\\$\\(" not in line:
        if ")" not in line:
                continue

    print(line)

    start = line.index("$(")    
    end = line.index(")")

    print(line[start+2:end])
```

I need to match the strings which are like $(hello). But now this even matches (hello).

Im really new to python. So what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you escaping `$` for the `in` check? It's not a regex there.

Comment: The expected output is `hello`, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
\$\(([^)]+)\)
```

It matches `$`, followed by `(`, then anything until the last `)`, and catches the characters between the parenthesis.

Here we did escape the `$`, `(` and `)` since when you use a function that accepts a regex (like `findall`), you don't want `$` to be treated as the special character `$`, but as the *literal* "$" (same holds for the `(` and `)`). However, note that the inner parenthesis didn't get quoted since you want to capture the text between the outer parenthesis.

Note that you don't need to escape the special characters when you're not using regex.

Answer (score 2):

I believe something along the lines of:

```
import re
data = "$(hello)"

matchObj = re.match( r'\$\(([^)]+)\)', data, re.M|re.I)
print matchObj.group()
```

might do the trick.

Comment: This will only catch the last character before the closing parenthesis. Also note that the `*` is greedy..

Comment: You  are correct, your [^)]+ solution fits better, I updated mine based on your advice. Have my up vote!

Comment: Now your answer is correct.. +1 Note that you can use `findall` without `M` and `I` flags.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I totally overlooked it since it worked on my test data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> escaper = re.compile(r'\$\((.*?)\)')
>>> escaper.findall("I like to say $(hello)")
['hello']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do it with regexes (I wouldn't necessarily; they can be hard to read).

1. Your for loop indentation is wrong.
2. "\$\(" means `\$\(` (you're escaping the brackets, not the `$` and `(`.
3. You don't need to escpae `$` or `(`. Just do `if "$(" not in line`
4. You need to check the $( is found before ). Currently your code will match "foo)bar$(baz".
5. Rather than checking if $( and ) are in the string twice, it would be better to just do the `.index()` anyway and catch the exception. Something like this:

```
with open('templates/data.xml', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        try:
            start = line.index("$(")
            end = line.index(")", start)
            print(line[start+2:end])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Edit: That will only match one $() per line; you'll want to add a loop.

Comment: Using a bare `except` clause is dangerous, especially with `pass` as the contents of the `except` block. And your code snippet nicely illustrates why. ;) You accidentally left out the `for line in s:` stuff, so when you attempt to call the `line.index` method a ` NameError` will be raised, but your naked `except: pass` will silently swallow that... BTW, it's not usual to terminate lines with semicolons in Python.

Comment: True; just an example though. Semicolons forever!

Comment: I changed it anyway. Also that is a thoroughly unjustified downvote.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't down-vote, but maybe one of the people who up-voted my comment down-voted. I probably _would have_ down-voted, eventually, if you hadn't fixed your code, but I like to give people time to respond to my comments before voting.

Comment: I undid my down vote (yes, it was mine) - I felt it was justified because of the error and masking it, but was always going to remove it if and when you responded.